# WSO2 get value from service response

Tags: xpath, wso2, wso2-esb

I have this rest api in WSO2 ESB:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="RestApi" context="/rest">
   <resource methods="POST GET" uri-template="/view/{symbol}" protocol="http">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/">
                  <soapenv:Header/>
                  <soapenv:Body>
                     <web:FahrenheitToCelsius>
                        <web:Fahrenheit>$1</web:Fahrenheit>
                     </web:FahrenheitToCelsius>
                  </soapenv:Body>
               </soapenv:Envelope>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('uri.var.symbol')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx" format="soap11"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
         <property name="msgbody" expression="$body" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="To" expression="get-property('msgbody')"/>
         </log>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"Status":"evgeni"}</format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <faultSequence/>
   </resource>
</api>
```

The important part is the `<outSequence></outSequence>`
The property `<property name="msgbody" expression="$body" scope="default" type="STRING"/>` returns the response from the soap service. It looks like this:

```
<soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/">     
        <FahrenheitToCelsiusResult>4.44444444444444</FahrenheitToCelsiusResult>
    </FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

I want to get just the value of `FahrenheitToCelsiusResult` (4.44444444444444). How can I do that?

I tried:

```
 <property xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
   name="msgbody" 
   expression="$body/soap:Body/FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse/FahrenheitToCelsiusResult" 
   scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

but it returns an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the namespace in the xpath expression as in below

```xml
<property expression="//ns:FahrenheitToCelsiusResult"
                    name="msgbody" scope="default" type="STRING"
                    xmlns:ns="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/"/>
```

For more information please refer to [this link](http://isharapremadasa.blogspot.com/2014/08/wso2-esb-property-mediator-performing.html)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<property name="tempValue" expression="//*[local-name()='FahrenheitToCelsiusResult']" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```